# How to get ARP bindings from the file into array

Tags: c, arp

I am trying to get the ARP table in Linux to an array with code posted below. I always get the addresses in the variables ip and mac, but when assigning to the array, it just shows some crazy numbers. Am I doing sth wrong? (I am not really skilled in programming)

```
struct ARP_entry 
{
  char IPaddr;
  char MACaddr;
  char ARPstatus;
  int timec;
};

static struct ARP_entry ARP_table[ARP_table_vel];


void getARP()
{
  int i=0;
  const char filename[] = "/proc/net/arp";
  char ip[16], mac[18], output[128];
  FILE *file = fopen(filename, "r");
  if ( file )
  {
    char line [ BUFSIZ ];
    fgets(line, sizeof line, file);
    while ( fgets(line, sizeof line, file) )
    {
      char  a,b,c,d;
      if ( sscanf(line, "%s %s %s %s %s %s", &ip, &a, &b, &mac, &c, &d) < 10 )
        {
    if ( ARP_table_vel > i)
    {
      ARP_table[i].IPaddr = ip;
      ARP_table[i].MACaddr = mac;
          ARP_table[i].ARPstatus = STATUS_CON;
      i++;
    }
        }
    }
  }
  else
  {
    perror(filename);
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to fix your structure and make the `char` variables into `char` arrays:

```
struct ARP_entry 
{
  char IPaddr[16];
  char MACaddr[18];
  char ARPstatus;
  int timec;
};
```

Then you need to do proper copies of the data so you can preserve them:

```
if ( ARP_table_vel > i)
    {
      snprintf(ARP_table[i].IPaddr, 16, "%s", ip);
      snprintf(ARP_table[i].MACaddr, 18, "%s", mac);
      ARP_table[i].ARPstatus = STATUS_CON;
      i++;
    }
```

Finally, the ARP table has a header, so you'll need to discard the first row.

Comment: what is the ARP_table_vel variable? how can I get the number of rows in the arp table in order to determine the ARP_Table size?